# When using "nohup", the print function won't print until the entire program is finished

Tags: bash, julia, nohup

Example in Julia: let's say I have a file "test.jl" with the following code:

```
for i in 1:3
    sleep(2)
    print("i = ", i, "\n") 
end
```

Then if I run

```
nohup julia test.jl &
```

I won't get each print result every 2 seconds. Instead, I will get all three print results at the end, which is useless for monitoring the progress of a loop that takes forever to complete.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's likely that output buffering is occurring. Try manually flushing standard output:

```
for i in 1:3
    sleep(2)
    print("i = ", i, "\n") 
    flush(stdout)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

nohup redirects standard output to $HOME/nohup.out until the process is completed then the results are printed onto screen all at once.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup
you can still redirect it live I think, something like tee might work or >&1. Not sure would have to check.

Comment: The man page for **nohup** does not mention buffering until the process completes; however, it is possible that a shell could change this behavior by masking **nohup** with a different implementation. With bash, at least, **nohup** just redirects to standard output by default (without buffering).

Comment: @ChrisHutchinson I'm assuming he doesn't know about that file, while it's writing there it is not writing to standard out, and is just waiting for that output at the end, that is effectively a buffer. Think I might have been wrong about that assumption of what was going wrong anyway though because just tried it for giggles and doesn't do an to stdout at the end anyway just stays in the file =/ Now I'm wondering where I remembered that happening from, used to use it a lot, maybe different implementations.